# data table form input updating form fields error

Tags: jquery, forms, datatables, postdata

I am using the data table, In which one column contains input field.
Now the problem is when I tried to update this field if the pagination is there only the current page data is submitting instead of all fields

[image]

Any solution here?

**Code Snippet**:

```
<form method="POST">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="dataTablesFullDesc" class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <?php _e('ID'); ?>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <?php _e('Project Name');?>
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        <?php _e('Status'); ?>
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        <?php _e('Assigned To'); ?>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <?php _e('Assigned By')?>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <?php _e('Estimated Time'); ?>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <?php _e('Time spent ');?><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" data-toggle='tooltip' title='<?php echo __("It will show time spent for today.") ?>'></i></th>
                    <?php if($isEmployee) { ?>
                    <th>
                        <?php _e('Hours Worked today')?>
                    </th>
                    <?php } ?>

                </tr>
            </thead>


            <?php if($isAdmin){ ?>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
            <?php }else{ ?>
            <tbody>
                <?php $i = 0 ;?>
                <?php foreach ($issues as $issue) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $issue['id']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php if($issue['projectid'] != 0) { ?>
                        <a href='<?php if(in_array("manageProject",$perms)) { ?>?route=projects/manage&id=<?php echo $issue[' projectid ']; ?><?php } else echo "#"; ?>'>
                                                                                                               <span><?php echo getSingleValue("projects","name",$issue['projectid']); ?> </span>
                                                                                                            </a>
                        <?php }else{ ?>
                        <a href='#'>
                            <?php _e('None'); ?>
                        </a>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="taskid[]" id="taskid" value="<?php echo $issue['id'] ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="timespent[]" id="timespent" value="<?php echo $issue['timespent'] ?>">

                    <td><b><?php echo $issue['name']; ?></b></td>

                    <td>
                        <?php if($issue['status'] == "To Do") echo "<span class='badge bg-green'>".__("To Do")."</span>"; ?>
                        <?php if($issue['status'] == "In Progress") echo "<span class='badge bg-blue'>".__("In Progress")."</span>"; ?>
                        <?php if($issue['status'] == "Done") echo "<span class='badge bg-gray'>".__("Done")."</span>"; ?>
                        <?php if($issue['status'] != "Done" && date('Y-m-d H:i', $issue['duedate']) < date('Y-m-d H:i') && $issue['duedate'] != "" || $issue['timespent'] > $issue['estimated_hrs']) echo "<span class='badge bg-red'>".__("Overdue")."</span>"; ?>
                    </td>
                    <!--<td><?php if($issue['duedate'] != "") echo date('d-m-Y h:i A', $issue['duedate']); else echo "<span class='text-muted'>".__("None")."</span>" ?></td>-->
                    <td>
                        <?php if($issue['adminid'] != 0) echo getSingleValue("people","name",$issue['adminid']); else echo "<span class='text-muted'>".__("Nobody")."</span>"; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php if($issue['assignid'] != 0) echo getSingleValue("people","name",$issue['assignid']); else echo "<span class='text-muted'>".__("Nobody")."</span>"; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo min_to_hours($issue['estimated_hrs']);?> Hours</td>
                    <?php $timesheets[$issue['id']] = isset($timesheets[$issue['id']])? $timesheets[$issue['id']]:0; ?>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo min_to_hours($timesheets[$issue['id']]); ?> Hours</td>
                    <?php if($isEmployee){ ?>
                    <td style="width: 14%;">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="totalwork" name="totalwork[]" min="0.00" step="0.01" value="<?php echo $timesheets[$issue['id']]/60; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="prevtimespent[]" value="<?php echo $timesheets[$issue['id']]; ?>" />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                    <?php } ?>

                </tr>

                <?php } ?>


            </tbody>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>

    </div>


    <?php if(isset($_GET['date'])){ ?>
    <input type="hidden" id="dateadded" name="dateadded" value="<?php echo $_GET['date']; ?>">
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="updateTimesheet">
    <input type="hidden" name="route" value="issues/all&date=<?php echo $_GET['date']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="routeid" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="section" value="">

    <?php if($isEmployee){ ?>
    <!--month dropdown-->
    <?php if(isset($_GET['peopleid'])){
                                $peopleid = $_GET['peopleid'];
                             }else{ 
                                global $liu;
                                $peopleid = $liu['id'];
                             } ?>
    <div class="pull-left">
        <select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible " onchange="window.location.href='?route=issues/all&date='+this.value+'&peopleid='+<?php echo $peopleid; ?>" id="respondid" name="respondid" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">


          <?php global $date;
              for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){ 
                $m = str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); 
                  echo  $first_date = date('Y-'.$m.'-01');
                 echo  $last_date  = date('Y-'.$m.'-t');

              $_GET['date'] = isset($_GET['date'])? $_GET['date']: date('Y-m-d');
                ?>
             <option value="<?php echo date('Y-'.$m.'-01');?>" <?php if(($first_date <= $_GET['date']) &&($last_date >= $_GET['date']) ) {echo "selected";} if((!$_GET['date']) && ($first_date <= $date) &&($last_date >= $date) ){echo "selected";}?> ><?php echo date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1)); ?> </option>
           <?php } ?>
          </select>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php $previousDate = strftime('%Y-%m-%d',(strtotime($timesheetDaysUpdate.'days ago')));?>
    <!--check the limit for update limit or restrict user to upload others timesheet-->
    <?php if((!isset($_GET['peopleid'])) || $liu['id'] == $_GET['peopleid']){ ?>
    <?php if(isset($_GET['date'])  && $_GET['date']<=$previousDate){ ?>
    <div class="pull-right"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" disabled><i class="fa fa-hourglass-half"></i> <?php _e('UPDATE TIME SHEET'); ?></button></div>
    <?php }else{ ?>
    <div class="pull-right"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-hourglass-half"></i> <?php _e('UPDATE TIME SHEET'); ?></button></div>
    <?php }}?>
</form>
```

I am using an array for input fields to submit the data.if the form is spread over pages then it's only catching the data for the current page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not updating your underlying data so that is probably your issue. I've had a small play and this looks like it might get you started:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  columnDefs: [{
    targets: [2],
    render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
      return `<input class="form-control totalwork" min="0.00" step="0.01" type="number" value="${data}" />`
    },
    orderDataType: "dom-value"
  }]
});

$(".btn-primary").click(function() {
  console.log(table.data())
});

$(".totalwork").on("change", function() {
  var cell = table.cell($(this).parent("td"));
  cell.data($(this).val());
})


$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-value'] = function(settings, col) {
  return this.api().column(col, {
    order: 'index'
  }).nodes().map(function(td, i) {
    return $('input', td).val();
  });
};
```

I'd also get your datatable to do more of the work! Here's a working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/xrmbar3c/).